# Raw string('\r') in regular expression in python doesn't works?

Tags: python, regex

Below is my raw string ('\r') test in python.

```
import re

a = re.compile('\d')
b = re.compile('\\d')
c = re.compile(r'\d')
d = re.compile(r'\\d')


print a.search("1")   # (O)
print a.search("\d")
print a.search("\1")

print b.search("1")   # (O)
print b.search("\d")
print b.search("\1")

print c.search("1")   # (O)
print c.search("\d")
print c.search("\1")

print d.search("1")   
print d.search("\d")  # (O)
print d.search("\1")
```

But it seems like raw string doesn't work.

For example, regular expression 'b' should catch the expression which is composed of "backslash + alphabet d", but it catches just number '1'....

And according to meaning of 'r', regular expression 'c' also should catch the string which is composed of 'backslash + alphabet d', but it didn't.

Could anyone explain this?

Thanks

Comment: Try printing `repr('\d')` and you may find enlightenment. (Hint: It's **exactly the same string literal** as `'\\d'` or `r'\d'`).

Comment: there are 2 escapes you need to worry about: the regex escape and the python escape. using `r` eliminates the python escape, but there is still the regex escape to worry about. not using `r` will parse the string FIRST with the python escapes, THEN with the regex escapes. thats why `'\d' == '\\d' == r'\d'`, the second one is parsed into the regex engine as `'\d'` like the first one since `\\\`` means something to the python 'escape manager' but `\d` doesnt, so it ignores it

Answer (score 1):

Your first three strings are exactly the same.

```
>>> '\d' == '\\d' == r'\d'
True
```

Thus, when run through the regex engine, they all match only a single digit. This is true because `'\d'` has no interesting behavior in the way that `'\n'` does, so parsing the backslash as literal is the only reasonable way for the Python interpreter to respond (barring a parse error -- which I'd argue might have been a better idea, but couldn't be implemented now without breaking compatibility).

By contrast, the same is **not** true of `\n`:

```
>>> '\n' == '\\n'
False
>>> '\\n' == r'\n'
True
```

---

Your fourth string, `r'\\d'`, is the same as `'\\\\d'`; thus, that it matches only the literal string `\d` should be no surprise.

Comment: Why isin't `'\n' == '\\n'` true? Is there no control code interpolation via double quoted strings in Python, and maybe single quote is a hybrid. This is not the case (for newline) of single quote in Perl.

Comment: @sln, `'\n'` is a single-character string containing only a newline in Python; `'\\n'` is a backslash literal followed by the letter `n`. As for the rest of your comment, I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: If Python does double quote interpolation of control codes (special escapes)  and does the same using single quotes, that is a flaw in logic. Why have single quotes at all ?

Comment: @sln, ...to be able to include double quotes in literals without needing to escape them? It's only a "flaw" if you expect language syntax identical to what you're already used to.

Comment: I've never encountered a high level language that interpolates control codes within single quotes. The `'"'` logic is flawed too because now you have to double escape control codes.

Comment: How does allowing double quotes to be literal inside single quotes (and the inverse) have anything to do with control code escaping?

Comment: Moreover, conventions among high-level languages vary more than you seem to think. Heck -- several come immediately to my mind where single quotes have meanings that have nothing to do with strings at all. (If we look at LISPs as individual languages rather than counting them as a single family, then not merely "several" but "tens").

Comment: @sln, JavaScript treats double-quotes and single-quotes as equivalents just like Python, and practices the same selective recognition of escape sequences (which I heartily dislike).  But I don't see your problem with `'\n' != '\\n'`.  As *regexes* they would match the same character, but the strings they represent are different.

Comment: @AlanMoore - Right, a natural newline (0x0a) will match the same as a `\n` as the engine see's it. The difference is when ignore whitespace is in affect, 0x0a is ignored while `\n` is not. @CharlesDuffy - If you have to maintain a mental list of `'\n' != '\\n'` control code escaping when constructing regex strings using single quotes, that's a _big_ problem.  If its just like double quotes that is a hassle of gigantic proportions. Why on earth would escape sequences other that escape itself and single quote, be recognized in single quotes. That's what double quotes are for.

Comment: @sln, ...and allowing folks to not need to think about backslash-escape sequences was the primary use case behind raw strings, in which they're not interpreted at all. As for "what [any particular piece of syntax] is for", that's specific to the language providing that syntax and its ecosystem of conventions and idiom.

Comment: In any event, this discussion is unlikely to be productive. Why are we wasting our collective time?